# PyPDF2: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PdfFileWriter found

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, pypdf

Reworking code to include Context Managers via with statements.  However I am receiving a Traceback: using Python 2.7 on Windows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CommissionSecurity.py", line 52, in <module>
    with open(output, 'w') as output_stream :
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PdfFileWriter found
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, I am trying to use PyPDF2 to encrypt pdf files, and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what I've done wrong here. Any guidance is appreciated.

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

for ID in file_dict:
    # print REP
    # print ID # debug: REP always coming over 764
    if ID in email_dict:
        # print file_dict[ID]
        path = "C:\\Apps\\CorVu\\DATA\\Reports\\AlliD\\Monthly Commission Reports\\Output\\pdcom1\\"
        file_path = os.path.join(path + file_dict[ID])
        writer = PdfWriter()
        reader = PdfReader(file_path)
        output_stream = (file_path, "wb")

        with open(file_path, "rb") as reader:
            with open(writer, "w") as output_stream:
                writer.encrypt(email_dict[ID][1])
                writer.write(output_stream)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: The open() function needs a string. Does `PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()` return a string?

Comment: You need to check what `PyDF2.PdfFileWriter()` returns ?

Comment: `with open(output, 'w') as outputStream`, instead of `output` use a file name for example `"C:myfile.pdf`

Comment: Thanks!  I replaced output with file, and that has fixed that issue, on to the next Traceback.

Comment: Should you be using '`wb`' as your `outputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

The code has several issues:

1. You don't use `reader`
2. You overwrite several variables

I guess what you want to do is this:

```py
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader

for ID in file_dict:
    # print REP
    # print ID # debug: REP always coming over 764
    if ID in email_dict:
        # print file_dict[ID]
        path = "C:\\Apps\\CorVu\\DATA\\Reports\\AlliD\\Monthly Commission Reports\\Output\\pdcom1\\"
        file_path = os.path.join(path + file_dict[ID])
        writer = PdfWriter()
        reader = PdfReader(file_path)
        output_stream = (file_path, "wb")

        with open("target.pdf", "w") as fp:    # this is
            writer.encrypt(email_dict[ID][1])  # the important
            writer.write(fp)                   # part
    else:
        continue
```

There are for sure other things necessary

Comment: Thank you.  This was one of my very first real world projects with Python. I appreciate the feedback.